# Apply pagination using Sunburnt highlighted search

Tags: solr, pagination, sunburnt

I am using Sunburnt Python Api for Solr Search. I am using highlighted search in Sunburnt it works fine.

I am using the following code:

```
search_record = solrconn.query(search_text).highlight("content").highlight("title")
records = search_record.execute().highlighting
```

Problem is it returns only 10 records. I know it can be change from solr-config.xml but issue is I want all records

I want to apply pagination using highlighted search of Sunburnt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the [SOLR-534](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-534) issue, which is still unresolved, you can't tell Solr to give you all results, but you can use a really high `rows` parameter depending on how many documents you expect to have in your index. I don't know anything about sunburnt but I believe something like this should work:

```
search_record = solrconn.query(search_text).paginate(rows=10000).highlight("content").highlight("title")
```

You just have to replace the rows value with something enough big depending on your index size.

Answer (score 0):

The [general approach](http://opensource.timetric.com/sunburnt/queryingsolr.html#pagination-with-django) to this is to use a paginator:

from django.core.paginator import Paginator

```
paginator = Paginator(si.query("black"), 30)
```

Once that's done, you can just paginate through everything:

```
for result in paginator.object_list:
    print result
```